# Parsing File with C# And Replace method

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to parse a a bunch of file with Replace method(string) while is doing what I expect: I feels is not practical. for instance I will process 10K files but in the First 72 I found like 30 values that need to be replace And this is the rule :

My Goal :"

My goal is to replace all Instance of  the ':'  Dont follows this Rules :

**1- the 2nd or 3rd Character foward is Not Another ':'
2-the 3rd or 2nd Chacarcter backward is Not Another  ':'**

All other should be Replaced

1- Any time that I found this character (:) and this character is not preceded by two char or three characters like :00: or :12A: I should replace it with an (*).

This is the method that I have so far.....

```
private static string cleanMesage(string str)
{
    string result = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        result = str.Replace("BNF:", "BNF*").Replace("B/O:", "B/O*").Replace("O/B:", "O/B*");
        result = result.Replace("Epsas:", "Epsas*").Replace("2017:", "2017*").Replace("BANK:", "BANK*");
        result = result.Replace("CDT:", "CDT*").Replace("ENT:", "").Replace("GB22:", "GB22*");
        result = result.Replace("A / C:", "A/C*").Replace("ORD:", "ORD*").Replace("A/C:", "A/C*");
        result = result.Replace("REF:", "REF*").Replace("ISIN:", "ISIN*").Replace("PAY:", "PAY*");
        result = result.Replace("DEPOSITO:", "DEPOSITO*").Replace("WITH:", "WITH*");
        result = result.Replace("Operaciones:", "Operaciones*").Replace("INST:", "INST*");
        result = result.Replace("DETAIL:", "DETAIL*").Replace("WITH:", "WITH*").Replace("BO:", "BO*");
        result = result.Replace("CUST:", "CUST*").Replace("ISIN:", "ISIN*").Replace("SEDL:", "SEDL*");
        result = result.Replace("Enero:", "Enero*").Replace("enero:", "Enero*");
        result = result.Replace("agosto:", "agosto*").Replace("febrero:", "febrero*");
        result = result.Replace("marzo:", "marzo*").Replace("abril:", "abril*");
        result = result.Replace("mayo:", "mayo*").Replace("junio:", "junio*").Replace("RE:", "RE:*");
        result = result.Replace("julio:", "julio*").Replace("septiembre:", "septiembre*");
        result = result.Replace("NIF:", "NIF*").Replace("INST:", "INST*").Replace("SHS:", "SHS*")
            .Replace("SK:", "");
        result = result.Replace("PARTY:", "PARTY*").Replace("SEDOL:", "SEDOL*").Replace("PD:", "PD*");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    return result;
}
```

And this is some sample data :"

```
:13: <-- keep /ISIN/XS SVUNSK UXPORTKRUDIT ZX PZY DZTU:<- replace UX DZ
TU:<- replace02ZUG12 RZTU:<- replace W/H TZX RZTU:<- replace0.00000 SHZRUS PZID:<- replace
0.000000 IDDSIN:<- replace
:31:  <-- keep 1201000100CD05302,24NSUC20523531001//00520023531014
:13: <-- keep /ISIN/XS0153242003 SVUNSK UXPORTKRUDIT ZX PZY DZTU:<- replace00ZUG12 UX DZ
TU:02ZUG12 RZTU:0.30241 W/H TZX RZTU:<- replace0.00000 SHZRUS PZID:<- replace
0.000000 ISIN:XS0153242003
:31: <-- keep 1201000100DD121253,25S202IMSSMSZUX534C//S0322211DF4301
S F/O 0150001400
:13: <-- keep XNF:<- replace this
```

Comment: You should probably try `Regex`.

Comment: And you should show your input data without the *keep* suggestion as well the expected output

Comment: It's not practical, indeed. Each call to `replace` creates a new temporary string. If you have a large file, or have to process many files, this will cause a HUGE waste of memory and CPU. You should check regular expressions or parsers. For example, it looks like you are trying to modify *tags*. Those tags look like a bunch of letters followed by `:`. You can capture that with `\w+:`. That won't capture spaces or slashes though. In order to *replace something though, you need to catch the tag name, eg: `(\w+):`. This captures the tag. You can replace this with `$1*`.

Comment: Check [Substitutions in regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: Your sample data seems to be all kinds of mixed up...

Comment: Also you say that your current code is doing what you want that confuses me slightly. My understanding from your description is that `:BNF:` should be untouched but your first replace will change that to `:BNF*`... Am I misunderstanding your requirements or are there in fact bugs in your current implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to replace all instances of the ':' character where it is not followed by 2 or 3 other characters. You could indeed try the System.Text.RegularExpressions library. You could then simplify your cleanMessage function in the following way.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

function string cleanMessage(string str)
{
     string pattern = ":(\s)"; //This will be a ':' followed by a space
     Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
     string replaceResult = rgx.Replace(str,"*$1") //this will replace the pattern with a '*' followed by a space. 
     return replaceResult;
}
```

If your goal is to replace all instances of the ':' character where it is not followed by 2 or 3 other characters and the 2nd or 3rd character forward or backward is not another ':'. You could change your cleanMessage to the following instead.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

function string cleanMessage(string str)
{
     string pattern = "([^;]{2}.):(\s[^:]{2})"; 
     //This will be 2 characters that cannot be ':' followed by anything then a ':' followed by a space and 2 more characters that cannot by ':' 
     //For instance, "BNF: :F" would FAIL and not get replaced but "BNF: HH" would pass and become "BNF* HH"
     Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
     string replaceResult = rgx.Replace(str,"$1*$2") //this will replace the : with a * 
     return replaceResult;
}
```

More information on the System.Text.RegularExpressions library replace can be found at 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: My goal is to replace all Instance of  the ':'  Dont follows this Rules :

1- the 2nd or 3rd Character foward is Not Another ':'
2-the 3rd or 2nd Chacarcter backward is Not Another  ':'

All other should be Replaced

Comment: I have edited my answer. Is it now closer to what you need? It should now only replace the : where it is no close to another one.

Comment: Awesome Thanks A lot

Answer (score 0):

As @dymanoid mentioned, regular expressions are a way to handle this. By using the following you'd get what you want:

```
result = Regex.Replace(str, "([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})\:", "$1*");
```

However for large datasets this won't perform well. In that case I'd look at walking through `str` character by character using a for-loop. If the current character is not a colon, add it to the result string and to a temporary string. When the current character is a colon (:) and the temporary string has a length of 2 or 3, write an asterisk to the result and clear the temporary string.
In this case you don't do any string replacement, you just select what to write to a new string.

[See here for a speed comparison between string replacement and regex replacement.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debuggingtoolbox/2008/04/02/comparing-regex-replace-string-replace-and-stringbuilder-replace-which-has-better-performance/)

Comment: This doesn't look like it does what the OP wants... The first susbtitution in his current code is`.Replace("BNF:", "BNF*")`. As you can see it should only be replacing the `:` whereas yours will replace the preceding characters too...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! this one will not work because is replacing this value  ( keep -----> :31: <-- keep  ) and I want to Replace this value -
replace --->RZTU:<- replace, because on 2 or 3 position back dosnt have another : character... but it's a good starting point. so Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Chris it Does! because I only want to replace the (:) not the complete word (BNF:), my Result here is (BNF*) I that is exactly what im looking for...

Comment: @IvanS: I am confused again... It really looks like it doesn't... If I run `var str = "BNF:"; var result = Regex.Replace(str, "[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3}:", "*");` then result will equal just `*` and not `BNF*`. Is that actually correct? I don't think so from what you've said previously but your last comment seemed to indicate it is correct...

Comment: @Chris you are Right! I was Talking about the replace method, not the REGEX, this {result = Regex.Replace(str, "[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3}\:", "*");} doesnt work it Replace the BNF also... I  thought you was talking about the replace and not the regex, this regex wont work for what im looking for... but is a good staring point  to learn about it.

Comment: @IvanS: Ah, no. I was saying that this answer doesn't match the behaviour of your replace. Effectively using your code as a basis for what behaviour should be expected from any given solution.

Comment: @IvanS my answer has changed to reflect your feedback.

Comment: AWESOME Works like A charm! Just Changed this    result = Regex.Replace(str, @"([a-zA-Z0-9]{4,5})\:", "$1*");  (4-5) Thanks A lot. SO do not allow me to Upvote, YET. but is an accepted answer, I will improve my Skills on Regex!